# How can I change the source folder setting in querydsl plugin?

Tags: querydsl

I am using QueryDSL jpa to my application and generated the Q helper entities.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-  /java</outputDirectory>
                    <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

But When  the plugin generates those java files, it got errors. Because it added target/generated-sources directory to the source folders  , not  target/generated-sources/java

How can I change the setting of source folder of this plugin? I want to specify the java directory where is under target/generated-sources

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for this. I should have taken a look more.
I changed the output directory and solved the errors.

```
<outputDirectory>target/generated-sources<outputDirectory>
```